# Suppressing argparse Error message - Python

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I'm using argparse to parse command line arguments. However at this time, I have an unusual request: I want to suppress the error message. For example:

```
 # !/usr/bin/env python
 try:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse')
        parser.add_argument('url', metavar='URL', type=str, nargs='+', 
                            help='Specify URL')
 except:
        print("Invalid arguments or number of arguments")
        exit(2)
```

so I only expect that to print `"Invalid arguments or number of arguments"` and nothing else. However, then I execute the code for example:

```
./foo --BOGUS
```

I'm getting the full usage message:

```
usage: foo [-h]
foo: error: too few arguments
foo: Invalid arguments or number of arguments
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`contextlib.redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr) to suppress the output from `argparse`:

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stderr

try:
    f = io.StringIO()
    with redirect_stderr(f):
        parser.parse_args()
except:
    print("Invalid arguments or number of arguments")
    exit(2)
```

Another option is to subclass `ArgumentParser` and override the [`exit`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/argparse.py#l2369) method.

Answer (score 4):

`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args(args=None, namespace=None)` might help. It parses the command line and returns a tuple (namespace, unknown_args).  namespace contains the args that were recognized and unknown_args is a list of args that weren't recognized.

```
ns, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args()
if unknown_args != []:
    # do something with erroneous args, e.g., silent exit

else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.9, use the [`exit_on_error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error) parameter:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(exit_on_error=False)
```

This allows you to catch errors manually:

```
try:
    parser.parse_args('--integers a'.split())
except argparse.ArgumentError:
    print('Catching an argumentError')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
url_command = parser.add_argument('url', metavar='URL', nargs='*', help='Specify URL(s)')
args = parser.parse_args()

url_command.nargs='+'  # format the usage correctly
if not args.url:
    parser.error('At least one URL is required!')
```

Comment: The question was how to suppress the error messages that argparse forces upon the user, not how to reformat the arguments so that the message is not thrown.